# Webdriver find elements by regex in python

Tags: python, regex, selenium

I am trying to extract all those tags whose class name fits the regex pattern frag-0-0, frag-1-0, etc. from [this link](http://de.vroniplag.wikia.com/wiki/Aak/002)

I am trying to retrieve it using the following code

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    for frg in frgs:
        driver.get(URL + frg[1:])
        frags=driver.find_elements_by_id(re.compile('frag-[0-9]-0'))
    for frag in frags:
            for tag in frag.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class^=fragmark]'):
                lst.append([tag.get_attribute('class'), tag.text])
    driver.quit()
    return lst
```

But I get an error. What is the right way of doing this?

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vroni.py", line 119, in <module>
    op('Aaf')
  File "vroni.py", line 104, in op
    plags=getplags(cd)
  File "vroni.py", line 95, in getplags
    frags=driver.find_elements_by_id(re.compile('frag-[0-9]-0'))
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/webscrape/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 281, in find_elements_by_id
    return self.find_elements(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/webscrape/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 778, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/webscrape/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 234, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/webscrape/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 398, in execute
    data = utils.dump_json(params)
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/webscrape/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/utils.py", line 34, in dump_json
    return json.dumps(json_struct)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0xb668b1b0> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Please check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Selenium `find_elements_by_id` method expects a simple string but the output of `re.compile` is a regular expression object which can be used for matching using its `match()` and `search()` methods, described below:

```
reobject = re.compile(pattern)
result = reobject.match(string)
```

Generally I would advise against using regular expressions for elements location. There must be another way to find this element. Perhaps class name, css or even XPath.

Comment: @EchchamaNayak that looks like a completely different question and problem now.

Comment: So should I ask about this separately?

Comment: @EchchamaNayak In this question your problem was that you used regular expression object instead of a string. This was solved I believe. Now you are asking how to get certain elements using other method and what's more important using another driver. So I would say, yes.

Comment: OK Sure. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The function `find_elements_by_id` [takes a string as an object, not a regular expression](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_id). I'm not sure if the function you're using can take regex, even as a string.

You might want to try [XPath](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).